# Воспроизвести аудиопоток .mp3 из интернета в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, аудио, потоки-данных

Мне нужно воспроизводить поток с этой ссылки: http://europaplus.hostingradio.ru:8014/ep-top256.mp3

Как это сделать в Python 3?

Answer (score 0):

Используйте библиотеку `pydub`.

`pip install pydub requests`

Этого достаточно:

```
import requests
from pydub import AudioSegment
from pydub.playback import play

url = "http://europaplus.hostingradio.ru:8014/ep-top256.mp3"
response = requests.get(url, stream=True)

# Проверка на то, получилось ли
if response.status_code == 200:
    # Конвертирование
    audio_data = AudioSegment.from_mp3(response.raw)
    
    # Воспроизведение
    play(audio_data)
else:
    print("Воспроизведение не сработало!")
```

Comment: Скажите вашему другу GPT что код не работает.

Comment: предупреждение: RuntimeWarning: Couldn't find ffmpeg or avconv - defaulting to ffmpeg, but may not work
  warn("Couldn't find ffmpeg or avconv - defaulting to ffmpeg, but may not work", RuntimeWarning)
код не работает

Comment: 1. почему вы думаете что это написал не я

Comment: 2. сейчас еще раз попробую преписать